# Windows Store App GridView get total width

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm building a Windows Store App that uses a GridView to show a list of items (basic, out of the box template).  I would like to know if I can get the total width that all the items take up.

Right now I'm taking the number of item columns and multiplying it by the total width of one of the items.  This is working, but it requires that my code behind knows way too much about my view.  I'd like to find the one property that has the width and just bind to it.

Thanks for any help!

Here is the code that I have to get the column width of the GridView

```
(itemGridView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as GridViewItem).ActualWidth
```

I don't have a good way to get the number of Columns, so that would also be helpful

Comment: Show what you have done in order to get the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActualWidth` property of the GridView should contain the information you are looking for.

If not, you could try to call `Measure` on the gridview to let it perform the required layout calculus and output its desired Size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  ActualWidth just gives me the length of the container, not the internal length.  I'll try Measure when I get a second.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that you want only the summed size of the items in the container. I don't think you can get that without knowing détails about the GridView Template. (summed margins and paddings) Measure will give you the same piece of information)

Comment: I updated the question with the code I use to get the width of one item.  From there I just need to figure out how many columns exist. any ideas on that?

Comment: I figured it out.... it was that Virtual Width thing that was throwing off my groove...  Set that to false and we were in business!